# Change sfdc Approval process email reply for wrong spelling APPROVED

Tags: email-template, approval-process

When we use approval process, we can approve through email. This is my question, because we can reply wrong spelled word in email, how can I modify the salesforce reply if the APPROVED word is misspelled. Thanks

Comment: Change your email template to emphasize the correct responses. Use styling to make it super apparent.  I simply used YES, NO to make it super clear to the responder. Note there is also Chatter approval if your users use chatter and the UI is much more obvious to the  approver

Answer (score 2):

From this Doc [Enable Email Approval Response](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=approvals_email.htm&language=en_US)

> Note: For salesforce.com to process your response the word 
>   APPROVE, APPROVED, YES, REJECT, REJECTED, or NO must be in 
>   the very first line of the reply email. Also, any comment
>   must be in the second line.

I can say that you have to pass the information(How to approve) in Email so that one can reply correctly.

Although it is possible to reply in other languages.

> Email approval response works in all languages that Salesforce supports. The response word or phrase is checked using the current user language dictionary. If no matches are found, the response word or phrase is checked in all other language dictionaries.

But i don't think misspelled words will work.